# Invalid Timestamp error in Merge statement (Teradata)

Tags: teradata

I am merge/inserting from stage table to final table.
I am receiving an error saying "Invalid Timestamp"

DDL of the Stage Table (For that particular column)

```
review_by TIMESTAMP(6),
```

DDL of Final Table (For that particular column)

```
review_by TIMESTAMP(6),
```

Data for this column in Stage table:

|review_by|
2017-11-23 14:30:20.483374 
2017-11-23 14:30:20.483374

Merge Statements:

```
review_by = CASE WHEN stg.review_by = '\N' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(stg.review_by AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.S(6)') END,
```

Insert Part Query

```
CASE WHEN stg.review_by = '\N' THEN NULL ELSE CAST(stg.review_by AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.S(3)') END,
```

Comment: What's the data type of `stg.review_by`, if it's a Timestamp you can't compare it to a string `'\N'`

Comment: its a timestamp, but since we are getting the original data from Hive chances are that we might get '\N' in place of NULL

Comment: That's not possible, it's either a string the you have to define it as a `VarChar(26)` or it's Timestamp, then it can't be `\N`. Try defining it as Timestamp in source and simplify to `CAST(NULLIF(stg.review_by, '\N') AS TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MI.SS.S(3)')`